Lengths of divided hypotenuse by bisector of right triangle of a triangle, that has circle inscribed in it
A circle is inscribed in a triangle ABC. Knowing that |AB| = 20cm, |AC| = 16cm and |BC| = 12cm, calculate the lengths of the segments into which the bisector of angle ACB divides side AB.
So from the Pythagoras theorem - the triangle is right triangle.
In a 45/45/90 triangle, the bisector would cut hypotenuse in half, but that's not the case.
I've thought about it for some time and I have no idea how to calculate it.

The triangle is Pythagorean indeed, but it's not a $45/45/90$, more likely a $±30/±60/90$ :-)

Ye, that's why I wrote "but that's not the case".

Why don't you use analytic geometry? Just give $C$ the coordinates $(0,0)$, $A$ gets $(16,0)$, $B$ gets $(0,12)$, you just need to calculate the intersection between the line $AB$ and the graph of $y=x$.

Thanks, it worked. It's 11+3/7 and 8+4/7.
